# Sound not playing in iPad and iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, ipad

I've done a website with Django where I record the audio, create an mp3 file and then use it on it. And I'm having a problem to **play the sound in Apple devices**. The sound plays correctly on Windows computers, Android devices and Mac computers.

**But when you access the website with iPhone or iPad, the sound doesn't play.**

I guess that the problem is on the way that I create the audio file in the Javascript.

```
$("#send_btn").click(function() {
    if(myFile != null){
      var csrf = $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();
      var url = "/xxxxxxxxxxx";
      var data = new FormData();
      data.append('recorded_audio', myFile);
      data.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', csrf);
      $.ajax({
          url: url,
          method: 'post',
          data: data,
          success: function(data){
            setTimeout(function() {
              window.location.href ="xxxxxxxxxxx";
            }, 2000);
          },
          cache: false,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false
      });
    }
    else{
      if(myFile == null){
        alert('You should record an audio to continue.');
      }
    }
  });

  record_btn.onclick = () => {
    $('#stop_btn').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#record_btn').addClass('hidden');
    $('#voice-bars').removeClass('hidden');
    device = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true});
    
    device.then(stream => {
      recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
      var items = [];
      recorder.start();

      recorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', e => {
        items.push(e.data);
      });

      recorder.addEventListener('stop', e => {
        blob = new Blob(items, { 'type': 'audio/mp3;' });
        myFile = new File([blob], 'audio.mp3');
        $('#source').attr("src", URL.createObjectURL(blob));
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will likely be due to browser compatibility with the JS sound API. If you are using chrome or Firefox on the devices it works with but safari on the apple devices, this will be your issue.

Refer to this for ios specifics: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/PlayingandSynthesizingSounds/PlayingandSynthesizingSounds.html

Comment: But the problem is the same in an iPad using a Chrome browser. So I guess that the problem is the device and not the browser